# Listener Interface in Writing Custom Events

Tags: java, events, interface, custom-events

I'm trying to write a custom event. I read that I should have 3 things: 1.The Component Class, 2.The Event Class and 3.The Listener Interface.

My problem is that I have to make a set of listeners in one of the classes like this:

```
public class MyEvent{
     private Set<EventListener> = new HashSet<>();
        public synchronized void addListener(EventListener listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
     }

      //and the rest of the code for firing event .. 

}
```

and here's the interface:

```
 public interface EventListener {
      void hungry(MyEvent event);
 }
```

I can't understand what it means to have a set of interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Here each elements of the `Set` is a listener of the Event :

```
 private Set<EventListener> = new HashSet<>();
```

In your design, it appears that multiple subscribers could subscribe to the notification of a same event.
For example, suppose that you have a event : "application started". It is possible that multiple objects want to be aware of this notification event.

Note that the event doesn't store generally the listeners (or observers) to.  It is the role of the component (or the observable) to store them. You should also provide a way to notify the listeners. For example :

```
public class MyComponent{
     private Set<EventListener> listeners = new HashSet<>();

     public synchronized void addListener(EventListener listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
     }

     public void notify(MyEvent myEvent){
        listeners.stream().forEach(e->e.hungry(myEvent));
     }
}
```

And you could set the relations between the objects it in this way :

```
MyComponent component = new MyComponent();
EventListener fooListener = new EventListenerImpl(...);
EventListener barListener = new EventListenerImpl(...);
component.addListener(fooListener);
component.addListener(barListener);
// trigger the event
component.notify(new HugryEvent());
```

Comment: thanks. I have a question about the observer and observable you mentioned. could you explain a little more how does that work? I read about it [here](http://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern) and I can't understand the difference between observer pattern and what I'm doing here with the event class, listener interface, and the component class?

Comment: Observer/Observable and Listeners are very close patterns. To make things simple, you should consider it as two ways to implement a communication without direct coupling for an object that will be notified as another object change its state. Both patterns work with events and rely on a decoupled communication and the low coupling is provided thanks to the interface usage (Observer or Listener).

Answer (score 0):

A set of interfaces is basically a collection of interfaces, or more colloquially, a "bunch" of interfaces.

The use of `HashSet`s prevents people from accidentally adding the same listener:

```
myEvent.addListener(this);
// some lines of code later...
myEvent.addListener(this);
```

The same listener would have the same hash code, and `HashSet.add` will not add the element to the set in such a situation. Note that interfaces also have `hashCode` methods because it is declared in `Object`.

The bad thing about adding two of the same listener is that from the listener's perspective, it would seem as if the event happened twice. Depending on what the event is, this can have a large effect.

One situation where this is undesirable that I can think of:

You are writing a game, and the event listener handles the click of a "buy" button. If the listener is called twice when the user only clicked it once, the player can unexpectedly lose some money.